# Why is the category of elements of a presheaf defined opposite to what it logically needs to be?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a category.
As far as I am aware, the following definitions are standard and generally accepted.

> **Definition 1.**
> Let $F \colon \mathscr{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be a covariant functor. The *category of elements* of $F$, denoted by $\mathbf{E}(F)$, is defined as follows:
>
> - An object of $\mathbf{E}(F)$ is a pair $(C, x)$ consisting of an object $C$ of $\mathscr{C}$ and an element $x$ of $F(C)$.
> - A morphism from $(C, x)$ to $(C', x')$ in $\mathbf{E}(X)$ is a morphism $f \colon C \to C'$ in $\mathscr{C}$ with $F(f)(x) = x'$.

> **Definition 2.**
> A *contravariant functor* $\mathscr{C} \to \mathscr{D}$ is a covariant functor $\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathscr{D}$.

> **Definition 3.**
> The *category of presheaves* on $\mathscr{C}$ is the functor category $[\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}}, \mathbf{Set}]$. In particular, a *presheaf* on $\mathscr{C}$ is a contravariant functor from $\mathscr{C}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$.

Let $X$ be a presheaf on $\mathscr{C}$.
It follows from the above definitions that the category $\mathbf{E}(X)$ is defined, and that it looks as follows:

- An object of $\mathbf{E}(X)$ is a pair $(C, x)$ consisting of an object $C$ of $\mathscr{C}$ and an element $x$ of $X(C)$.
- A morphism from $(C, x)$ to $(C', x')$ in $\mathbf{E}(X)$ is a morphism $f \colon C' \to C$ in $\mathscr{C}$ with $X(f)(x) = x'$.

However, all sources I’ve seen¹ give a definition of $\mathbf{E}(X)$ that is opposite to what it logically needs to be:
a morphism from $(C, x)$ to $(C', x')$ is defined as a morphism $f \colon C \to C'$ with $X(f)(x') = x$.

What confuses me about this is that

- it introduces a logical contradiction, which is *absolutely never* allowed;
- it doesn’t even give us anything useful:
  the category that people want to define already exists, they just need to denote it as $\mathbf{E}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}$ instead.

> **Question.**
> In view of these two points, why do people use the prevalent definition of “category of elements of a presheaf”?

My only guess is that the prevalent definition of $\mathbf{E}(X)$ exists in this form for historical reasons, and that people don’t want to go against historical inertia.² ³
But I hope that there is a better reason, which I’m missing.

---

¹ Tom Leinster’s *Basic Category Theory* (Definition 6.2.16), Emily Riehl’s *Category Theory in Context* (Definition 2.4.2), Mac Lane’s and Moerdijk’s *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* (page 41), the Wikipedia article *Category of elements*.

² Riehl’s book tries to adress this problem.
In it, the category of elements is defined separately for contravariant functors and for contravariant functors (Definitions 2.4.1 and 2.4.2).
However, this seems to be logically inconsistent with the above Definition 2 (which is used in the book), since contravariant functors are actually covariant functors in disguise.

³ The Wikipedia article *Category of elements* also acknowledges that “[…] the direction of the arrows is reversed. […] Consequentially, in the spirit of adding a "co" in front of the name for a construction to denote its opposite, one should rather call this category the category of coelements of $P$.”
(The article uses $P$ instead of $X$.)

Comment: Are you expecting an answer other than "because it's typically more useful to define it that way"? Regarding whether it should be "forbidden", if the contradictory terminology bothers you, you already have two solutions: Riehl's definitional fix (separate definitions depending on the variance) and Wikipedia's terminological fix (category of coelements).

Comment: IMO category of elements in Riehl is the natural one. Coelements should (imo) be where the maps of the chosen element go backwards relative to the morphism $F(f)$ in Set rather in the base category. This way elements behaves like elements of sets, and coelements are the notion of elements for Set-op.

Comment: Both definitions are useful. One situation where you need both is the following construction of a weighted colimit in $\textbf{Set}$: given $G : \mathcal{I}^\textrm{op} \to \textbf{Set}$ and $F : \mathcal{I} \to \textbf{Set}$, the colimit of $F$ weighted by $G$ can be identified with the set of connected components of $\textbf{E} (G) \times_\mathcal{I} \textbf{E} (F)$, where $\textbf{E} (G) \to \mathcal{I}$ is the discrete fibration and $\textbf{E} (F) \to \mathcal{I}$ and is the discrete opfibration.